# Не подключается библиотека MySQL-Connector Java

Tags: java, mysql

У меня есть код, который должен подключаться к внешней MySQL датабазе. Я подключил к проекту библиотеку mysql-connector-j и добавил в код строку перед подключением `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. Но IDE выводит ошибку `Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException`. При запуске кода выводится эта же ошибка. Пробовал прописывать `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` но ничего не происходило. Это происходит в Eclipse и Intenji IDEA.
Вот код:

```
package ru.aloyen.hwidban;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    private String db_ip, db_port, db_password, db_user, db_name, ban_message;
    private Connection con;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getLogger().info("\nStarting a plugin...");
        
        try {
            this.getLogger().info("Fetch a config...");
            db_ip = this.getConfig().getString("mysql.ip");
            db_port = this.getConfig().getString("mysql.port");
            db_password = this.getConfig().getString("mysql.password");
            db_user = this.getConfig().getString("mysql.user");
            db_name = this.getConfig().getString("mysql.name");
            ban_message = this.getConfig().getString("ban_message");
        } catch (Throwable err) {
            this.getLogger().warning("MySQL configuration are cursed. Rewriting default config and shutdown a plugin...");
            this.saveDefaultConfig();
            this.getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
        }
        this.saveDefaultConfig();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//" + db_ip + ":" + db_port + "/" + db_name, db_user, db_password);
        } catch (SQLException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        this.getLogger().info("Hwid Ban plugin now is shuting down...");
    }
}
```

Вот скриншот с подключенными библиотеками:
[image: Библиотеки]

Как это исправить?

Comment: См. [EngSO: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse) -- по какой-то причине  .jar-файл с драйвером не обнаруживается в вашем проекте.  Возможно стоит проверить права доступа к этому файлу.

Comment: Я пытался исправить это по тому способу, который описан в той теме, которую вы отправили. Ни Maven фикс, ни простое добавление .jar не помогли.